# How to add vertex weight panel into custom addon panel?

Tags: scripting

when you select a single vertex in edit mode, under item tab, if it has been assigned to vertex groups, there is a Vertex Weights Subpanel. how can I append it to my custom addon tab? more specifically the green part?
[image]

the closest info I can find is for the Vertex Group Panel
where you can append it to a panel class with the following code:

```
row.template_list("MESH_UL_vgroups", "", ob, "vertex_groups", ob.vertex_groups, "active_index", rows=rows)
```

full code [here](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/release/scripts/startup/bl_ui/properties_data_mesh.py) at line 242

Also, for the vertex group I found a keyword "DATA_PT_vertex_groups" which is how I get a link from above. for vertex weight there is a keyword: "PANEL_PT_vertexWeightLayersPanel", I am not sure if it is useful.